# How to print one observation in one single line?

Tags: sas

SAS will automatically split a long observation into several pages. I wonder how I can use the options to print one obs in one single line.

Comment: Where do you want to print your output? The results listing, the log, or an external file?

Comment: print in the .lst file or in the output window of sas.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the [linesize](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-sysop-linesize.htm) setting?

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using ods for the output, that wont cut the line:

```
ods html file='filename.xls' style=minimal;
    proc print data=dataset(obs=1);
    run;
ods html close;
```